# RIGHT WHERE in JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, where

Necesito aplicar un filtro a un solo lado de un join sin que afecte al otro lado

Debo de hacer un join entre 2 tablas, actualmente lo hago con un 2 for lo que hace la consulta sea lenta, la consulta se compone de varias variables las cuales son

> idPartida, noParte, componente, precio unitario, estado

pero necesito agregar la cantidad que se encuentra en otra tabla y su variable en comun es la variable de

> idPartida

y el join que utilizo tiene esta estructura

```
SELECT L.idPartida, C.cantidad, L.noParte, L.componente L.precioUnitario, L.clasificacion FROM listadeprecios as L LEFT JOIN coleccionadordeprecios as C on C.idPartida=L.idPartida;
```

requiero de todos los datos de la lista de precios pero requiero las cantidades de una selección previa la cual represento con un FK de la segunda tabla pero al momento de aplicar el where no me arroja todos los resultados de la primera tabla y si no pongo el where me arroja 17,000 datos de los cuales solo me son utiles como 200, que basicamente es el filtro que se aplicaria con el where

una forma de hacer lo que quiero seria hacer una consulta masomenos asi

```
SELECT idPartida, noParte, componente, precio unitario, estado, (SELECT cantidad FROM coleccionadordeprecios as C where L.idPartida=C.idPartida AND C.idFK=200) as cant FROM listadeprecios as L;
```

pero creo eso puede hacer mas lenta la consulta, les agradesco si me pueden responder, no me bannen la pregunta mejor comentenme para corregirla si algo no lo deje claro

Comment: Lee sobre lefts join quiza sea lo que buscas, en este tipo de JOIN si no se satisfasen las condiciones de la segunda tabla aun asi, se arrojaran los registros de la primera, explicando eso a grandes rasgos

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tiene porque coloca el predicado `and C.idFK=200` en el where. Intente colocándolo en la misma cláusula `on` del `left join` con eso no se descartarían las filas que no tengan datos en su tabla `coleccionadordeprecios` algo como  `SELECT L.idPartida, C.cantidad, C.idFK FROM listadeprecios as L LEFT JOIN coleccionadordeprecios as C on C.idPartida=L.idPartida and C.idFK=200;`

Comment: @MauricioOrtega Simon ya quedo gracias, Solo que segun yo ya lo habia intentado o.o pero quizas me falto agregar bien la condicion, pero ya quedo gracias